# Windows 10 Update Assistant Resets At ~85%

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

When the percentage for the download reachs about 85%, it completely restarts the download (goes down to 0%). It's done this twice today, and I'm not sure why.

- **Edition**: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit
- **Version**: 1511
- **Build**: 10586.1007

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: One more thing, the Update Assistant says "The latest version is 15063", which I assume is the one it's going to download.

Comment: Why are you attempting to install a 1511 instead of 1703?  You need to install 1703 not 1511 if you want help

Comment: This is my current version.

Comment: Except, 1511 isn't the current version, any event your problem is caused by a hardware conflict with the feature update your attempting to install

Comment: It's MY current version, is what I'm obviously stating! I would update every couple of months, but I didn't realize it wouldn't install because one of the previous updates was corrupted. Hence why I'm on such a late version.

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me.  Download the current Windows 10 ISO, mount the ISO, and install the feature update that way.  If you still get this behavior then you have a hardware conflict

Comment: Downloading the iso file now, I'll see how it goes. The Update Assistant said everything was compatible, but who knows.